# How to make a model-view-controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model-view

I need to modify my code so that it becomes a model-view-controller. Since I'm a total noob when it comes to programming my head aches if I'm honest. Any help how to do this would be appreciated.

For a better understanding I will paste the whole task so you can see what my code is for.

*In one pasture there are 200 bustling sheep. The flock consists of 95 white sheep, 60 black sheep and 45 white-black sheep. The shepherd now wants to divide them up so that the corresponding wool can be sheared by color. Help him write a small script so that he can better order his sheep. Please implement the first three points with variables, arrays, mathematical operators and functions.
Tip: For a better overview, you can also define your own functions.

1. Store the sheep in appropriate groups. Work out a concept that works with variables and arrays.
2. Create 200 sheep with the properties name, number of legs, color and assign them to a stable!
3. Assign the sheep randomly to a number of sheds.*

Here's my code sample, as I said the following part has to become a model-view-controller. How do i do this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$stableForEachColor = array("stableForWhite", "stableForBlack", "stableForWhiteBlack");
// Function to get the full amount of all sheep
function legs($all)
{
    $legs = 4;
    return $all * $legs;
}

$whiteSheep = 95;
$blackSheep = 60;
$whiteBlackSheep = 45;
$all = $whiteSheep + $blackSheep + $whiteBlackSheep;
echo "At the pasture there are $all sheep in total.\n\n";



$legs = legs($all);
echo "All sheep combined have $legs legs in total.\n\n";

// Names of the white sheep
for ($colorWhite = 1; $colorWhite <= $whiteSheep; $colorWhite++) {
    echo "Wooly $colorWhite is white.\n";
}
// Names of the black sheep
for ($colorBlack = 1; $colorBlack <= $blackSheep; $colorBlack++) {
    echo "Wooly $colorBlack is black.\n";
}

// Names of the white-black sheep
for ($colorWhiteBlack = 1; $colorWhiteBlack <= $whiteBlackSheep; $colorWhiteBlack++) {
    echo "Wooly $colorWhiteBlack is white-black.\n";
}



$stable = array('white_sheep' => $colorWhite, 'black_sheep' => $colorBlack, 'white-black_sheep' => $colorWhiteBlack);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($stable);

$sheep = 200;
$stablesC = 4;
for ($i = $sheep; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $stables[rand(0, ($stablesC - 1))] += 1;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($stables);
```

Comment: `the following part has to become a model-view-controller`...does it? The assignment text you've posted doesn't require that. And MVC is a concept, not a specific implementation. It's a reasonable complex concept though, and the implementations which do exist, for powering web applications, are themselves fairly complex. Ensure you understand the concept first, and then try to apply it to your scenario and work out what you need. Easier to start from scratch and try to convert what you've got probably.   MVC isn't really for complete programming beginners though, IMHO.

Comment: P.S. It's too broad a task to ask for a full sample on SO - we're not a free write-my-code service. Nor do we provide tutorials or conceptual teaching. We'll answer a specific question about a specific issue in your code. We won't do a big redesign. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Most of that task involves just restructuring your code, to separate...well, the M, V and C bits.

There is no one true answer, but based on a quick glance i suspect the model part may look roughly like:

- abstract class Sheep { ... }

  - with private properties $name , $numberoflegs, $color
  - with public function getName() and getLegs() and getColor()
  - with public function setName($x) and setLegs($x)
  - with public __construct($color, $shed, ?$legs, ?$name) function
- class WhiteSheep   extends Sheep { ... }

  - with public __construct($shed) function
- class BlackSheep   extends Sheep { ... }

  - with public __construct($shed) function
- class StripedSheep extends Sheep { ... }

  - with public __construct($shed) function
- abstract class SheepCollection implements Iterator { ... }

  - public function addSheep($sheep)
  - public function removeSheep($sheep)
  - public function transferSheep($sheep, $shed)
  - public function setName($x)
  - public function getName()
  - public function getLegs()
  - public function getAmountOfSheep()
  - private property $name
  - private array $sheep
  - public __construct($name)
- class Stable extends SheepCollection { ... }

  - with public __construct()  (could be a singleton)
- class Shed extends SheepCollection { ... }

  - with public __construct($name)

and your view layer can likely be very slim (just a couple methods in total).

anyway, maybe this gives you a little of an idea on where to start.

Comment: A little note: Imho, a stable can not **be** a sheep collection. So, semantically, `class Stable extends SheepCollection` is not correct. Though, a stable can **have** a sheep collection. For example, a `SheepCollection` instance can be passed to a `Stable` object in the constructor. Dito for the shed.

Comment: Fair point; was trying to keep it simple-ish since im guessing its just homework :) the stable is likely just there as initial collection, before a sheep has been assigned to a shed;